# Placing inline adsense in between posts on blogger mobile's homepage

Tags: mobile, blogger

How i can achieve this below?

Placing adsense in between posts on blogger mobile homepage. This can easily be done for desktop homepage view but it seems very difficult to achieve for mobile homepage also.

I have seen a blog do this and i need someone to help out on how to also implement it.

See sample of a blog do this below.

[sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upKAj.)

[sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3HXG.png)

Comment: Just  a suggestion, Don't put ads in that place, its annoying

Answer (score 0):

Search your code for `<b:include data='post' name='mobile-post'/>` and paste this code below it

```
    <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'> 
     <b:if cond='data:post.includeAd'>
       <div class='inline-ad'>
         <data:adCode/>
       </div>
     </b:if>
   </b:if>
```

Comment: Thank you Bassa but i'm sorry it didn't work.
What i actually want is to have the inline ads which currently displays on my website to display on the mobile view too.
The website is www.jobnetworknigeria.com have a look and kindly advise.

Comment: try to take adsense code form adsense site and put it there

Comment: So blogger prevent you from doing that. my advice is to show desktop template on mobile devices and make the template responsive according to the template in your second image.

Comment: Thank you
So how do i do that?

Comment: To make your blogger template mobile friendly please read  [this article](http://www.bloggingspell.com/make-blogger-mobile-friendly) it needs to HTML and CSS knowledge.